# Issue upgrading Morphia to 2.0.0

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin, morphia

I'm upgrading Morphia to version 2.0.0 (currently 1.3.2) and I'm having an issue removing the deprecated createQuery method for this code snippet, since i need to do an elem match

```
val builder = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
        .add("items", BasicDBObject("\$elemMatch", BasicDBObject("\$and", arrayOf(
                BasicDBObject("shipments.correlations.id", pickupId),
                BasicDBObject("status.value", BasicDBObject("\$in", ItemStatus.values().filter {
                    it.value != ItemStatus.SHIPPED.value
                }.map { it.value }))
        ))))
if (excludeOrdersIds.count() > 0) {
    builder.add("id", BasicDBObject("\$nin", excludeOrdersIds))
}
return morphia.createQuery(Order::class.java, builder.get()).asList(FindOptions().limit(limit))
```

In version 2.0.0 I can't find a method that let me do the elem match or let me use the DBObject returned by the Mongo driver BasicDBObjectBuilder, like I was doing in this code snippet.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade through each intervening release and follow the deprecations, you'll get there much more cleanly by the end.  The 2.0 release has dropped all use of `DBObject` in favor of the modern `Document`.  But you really should at least bounce through the 1.6 release as there are deprecations there to prep you for moving to 2.0.

Comment: Ok, so let's say that I can obtain a Document instead. Which method should I use in order to interact with it using Morphia? Right now I've migrated all the codebase except that code snippet. Or, is there any way I could perform and elemMatch with the new Morphia directly?

Comment: `elemMatch` is done using [`Filters.elemMatch`](https://morphia.dev/2.0.2/javadoc/dev/morphia/query/experimental/filters/Filters.html#elemMatch(java.lang.String,dev.morphia.query.experimental.filters.Filter...))